# Getting old indexed elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have lot of data indexed in my elasticsearch.

I deleted elasticsearch folder and then extarct again fresh zip of elasticsearch and start the elasticsearch server.

I am surprised because after staring new elasticsearch server, I again found all old data and this problem persists again and again.

Can any please help me? I don't want to get all old data indexed in elasticsearch.

Regards

Comment: Everything is in the data folder by default. If you delete that folder you'll start from scratch. Are you storing the index somewhere else or using the default configuration?

Comment: Is it possible that you have another server running somewhere on your local network and it replicates data back to the newly started server?Could you run `curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health` and post here the output?

Comment: @imotov below is the output after hitting localhost:9200/_cluster/health ::     {"cluster_name":"elasticsearch-opt-cluster","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":5,"active_shards":5,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":5}

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with multiple nodes on the same cluster. Did you check the java processes running? You could maybe have an elasticsearch hanging somewhere which writes in that folder...

Comment: Ok, I'll put my comment in a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the cluster health response it's not a problem with multiple nodes running on the same cluster as suggested by Igor. I'd suggest you to check the java processes running. You could maybe have an elasticsearch hanging somewhere which keeps writing in that folder.